# Property Designation does not exist error

Tags: angular, angular13

This is Angular CRUD based application. I want to collect user inputs . So, I m using `REST API` URL to accomplish that task.  when i run `ng serve` it gives me following error. I assumed the error is in `create.component.ts` ,I also created `Employee` Class Separately .

[image]

```
export class Employee implements IEmployee {
  public birth_date: string;
  public first_name: string;
  public last_name: string;
  public gender: string;
  public hire_date: string;
  public salaries: ISalary;
  public designations: IDesignation;
  public emp_no: string;

  constructor(
    birth_date: string,
    first_name: string,
    last_name: string,
    gender: string,
    hire_date: string,
    salaries: ISalary,
    designations: IDesignation,
    emp_no: string,
  ) {
    this.birth_date = birth_date;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.hire_date = hire_date;
    this.salaries = salaries;
    this.designations = designations;
    this.emp_no = emp_no;

  }


}
```

`classes/Employee.ts`

```
export class Employee implements IEmployee {
  public birth_date: string;
  public first_name: string;
  public last_name: string;
  public gender: string;
  public hire_date: string;
  public salaries: ISalary;
  public designations: IDesignation;
  public emp_no: string;

  constructor(
    birth_date: string,
    first_name: string,
    last_name: string,
    gender: string,
    hire_date: string,
    salaries: ISalary,
    designations: IDesignation,
    emp_no: string,
  ) {
    this.birth_date = birth_date;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.hire_date = hire_date;
    this.salaries = salaries;
    this.designations = designations;
    this.emp_no = emp_no;

  }


}
```

`create.component.ts`

```
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {


  employee: Employee [] = [];
 

  constructor(private requestHandlerService: RequestHandlerService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  save() {
    this.requestHandlerService.postRequest("emp", this.employee).subscribe({
      next: (resultData) => {
        console.log(resultData);
      },
      error: (errorData) => {
        console.log(errorData);
      }
    })
    console.log(this.employee);
  }


}
```

`create.component.html`

```
<p>create works!</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <h1>IEmployee Profile</h1>

      <h3>1.Profile Detail</h3>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.first_name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.last_name" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Birth Date</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.birth_date" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Gender</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.gender" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Hire Date</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.hire_date" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>

      </div>

      <h3>2.ISalary Details</h3>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Amount</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.salaries.salary" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>From Date</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.salaries.from_date" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>To Date</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.salaries.to_date" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>

      <h4>2.IDesignation Details</h4>
      <div class="container">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.designations.title" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>From Date</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.designations.from_date" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>To Date</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="employee?.designations?.to_date" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button (click)="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save Entries</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in create.component.html line 62 change `employee.designations.to_date` to `employee?.designations?.to_date`

Comment: @abdella , it doesnt work

Comment: Post all content of create.component.html

Comment: @abdella Updated. please check now

Comment: `employee: Employee [] = []` is an array, so you have to iterate using `ngFor` to access `employee?.designations?.to_date`

Comment: First thing to clarify, the page and model to submit is for **Single** employee (object) or **Multiple** employee**s** (array)?

Comment: Single Employee (object)

Answer (score 0):

Since as discussed in the comment that `employee` is an **object**.

Change the `employee` type as `Employee` and initialize with an object with `{}`.

```js
employee: Employee = {};
```